# Advanced Functions, How to simplify $\tan \frac{5\pi}{12}$?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I was asked to find the exact value of $\,\tan \left(\frac{5\pi}{12}\right)$, so I did up until this point where I got completely stuck.

I split the ratio into two, so $\;\dfrac{5\pi}{12} = \dfrac{\pi}4 + \dfrac{\pi}6\,.$

using the formula, $\tan(x+y) = \dfrac{\tan x+\tan y}{1-\tan x\tan y}$:

$$\tan(\pi/4 + \pi/6) = \frac{1+1/\sqrt 3 }{1-(1)(1/\sqrt 3)
}$$

...

$$\tan(\pi/4 + \pi/6) = \frac{3+\sqrt3}{ 3-\sqrt3 }$$

I'm stuck here, I looked up the answer online, and apparently, you have to times numerator and denominator both by $\,3+\sqrt3\,,\,$ but it's cheating, I don't understand why you have to do that.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Cheating?! It’s the method of using *rational conjugates*, and it is extremely common and useful. You should consider it a tool in your toolbox, not a “cheat”.

Comment: If it's valid and works and you understand why it works it can't be "cheating".  As FShrike points out is a tool and you should use it as frequently as any other tool.  Of course like all tools you have to learn it a first time and its not fair to expect all students to come up with it on their own.  Anyway you don't "have" to do it but it's a really really good way to do it.

Comment: Sorry, I just was never taught about rational conjugates or forgot about it.

Comment: In general, when trying to "rationalize the denominator" of an expression like $$\frac{x}{a+b\sqrt d},$$ we multiply the numerator and denominator by $a-b\sqrt d.$ This is just a standard trick. The only reason we rationalize denominators is that it is easier to spot when two values are equal.

Comment: It's only cheating if you multiply by 0, otherwise you are OK.

Comment: Although technically $\frac {3+\sqrt 3}{3-\sqrt 3} =\frac {5+2\sqrt 3}2$ so $\frac {3+\sqrt 3}{3-\sqrt 3}$ *might* be an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I looked up the answer online, and apparently, you have to times numerator and denominator both by $3+\sqrt3$, but it's cheating, I don't understand why you have to do that.

The denominator $x = 3-\sqrt3 \;$ is an irrational number whose decimal expansion is non-terminating and non-repeating. So we do not know its exact value (to infinitely many decimal places) and hence are unable to compute a satisfying numerical value (decimal expansion) of the fraction $\dfrac{3+\sqrt3}{3-\sqrt3}\,$ using eg, long division.

However on making the denominator a rational number, aka "rationalizing the denominator" using the identity $(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2 \;$ which removes the square roots, we get a nicer  $2+\sqrt{3}\,$ which can be computed to limited accuracy by hands/calculators or to much larger precision using computers.

Comment: You won't get $2-\sqrt3<1$ since the denominator is smaller than the numerator.

Comment: @SuzuHirose Yes, thank you. Fixed the sign.

Comment: The reason we rationalize the denominator is not because of difficulty calculating the value. We still have the problem of $\sqrt3$ after rationalized. But rationalized denominators tend to have a unique form, so we rationalize for the same reason we reduce fractions - to get to a canonical form.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Oh thank you, that is indeed the best reason.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Another way to realize the solution:
\begin{align*}
\tan\left(\frac{5\pi}{12}\right) & = \tan\left(\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{5\pi}{6}\right)
\end{align*}

Now you can apply the corresponding half-angle formula.

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

So, you've remembered (or re-derived) that $\tan(\frac{\pi}{4}) = 1$ and $\tan(\frac{\pi}{6}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$, and plugging this into your sum-of-angles formula gives:

$$\tan(\frac{5\pi}{12}) = \frac{\tan(\frac{\pi}{4}) + \tan(\frac{\pi}{6})}{1 - \tan(\frac{\pi}{4})\tan(\frac{\pi}{6})} = \frac{1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}{1 - (1)(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})}$$

But fractions within fractions are just ugly, so let's multiply numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{3}$.

$$\tan(\frac{5\pi}{12}) = \frac{\sqrt{3} + 1}{\sqrt{3} - 1}$$

And this is a perfectly valid way of expressing the value (which numerically is approximately 3.732051).  But it's often considered good style to “rationalize the denominator”, i.e., have √ signs only on top and never on bottom.

Recall the FOIL method for multiplying two binomials, and that $$(a - b)(a + b) = a^2 + ab - ab - b^2 = a^2 - b^2$$

So, if you multiply a binomial by the same thing but with the opposite sign, then only *squared* terms occur in the product, so any √ signs go away.  So let's multiply the denominator by $\sqrt{3} + 1$.  Of course, we need to multiply the numerator by $\sqrt{3} + 1$ too so that the value of the expression doesn't change

$$\frac{\sqrt{3} + 1}{\sqrt{3} - 1} \times \frac{\sqrt{3} + 1}{\sqrt{3} + 1}$$
$$= \frac{3 + 2\sqrt{3} + 1}{3 - 1}$$
$$= \frac{4 + 2\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
$$= 2 + \sqrt{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\tan\left(\dfrac{5\pi}{12}\right)=\tan\left(\dfrac\pi4+\dfrac\pi6\right)=\dfrac{3+\sqrt3}{3-\sqrt3}=\dfrac{3+\sqrt3}{3-\sqrt3}\cdot\dfrac{3+\sqrt3}{3+\sqrt3}=$

$=\dfrac{\left(3+\sqrt3\right)^2}{\left(3-\sqrt3\right)\left(3+\sqrt3\right)}=\dfrac{9+3+6\sqrt3}{9-3}=\dfrac{12+6\sqrt3}6=$

$=\dfrac{6\left(2+\sqrt3\right)}6=2+\sqrt3\;.$

You need to multiply both numerator and denominator by $\,3+\sqrt3\,$ in order to eliminate square roots in the denominator.

On the other hand, if you multiply both numerator and denominator by the same number, it does not change the value of the fraction.